# fluent nhibernate, inheritance and using derived list types

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I am still on learning curve and I stuck. I am using fluent nhibernate with automapping. I have some conventions configured which works (someone else did it).

I have following structure:

```
LoyaltyProgram
UniversalProgram : LoyaltyProgram
OtherProgram : LoyaltyProgram
```

They using table per hierarchy which works, so conventions in general are OK.
I created some rules for storing customer points:

```
BasePointsRule
AmountPointsRule : BasePointsRule
TresholdPointsRule : BasePointsRule
```

BasePoints contains property

```
public virtual UniversalProgram UniversalProgram { get; set; }
```

I tried to do following, in class UniversalProgram:

```
public virtual ICollection<AmountPointsRule> AmountPointsRules { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<TresholdPointsRule> TresholdPointsRules { get; set; }
```

I wish to be able to get and set them both.

I have set discriminator.

```
class BasePointsRuleMap : IAutoMappingOverride<BasePointsRule>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<BasePointsRule> mapping)
    {
        mapping.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("basepointstype");
    }
}
```

But looking into database I have following foreign key created on table BasePointsRule:

```
alter table `BasePointsRule` 
    add index (UniversalProgramId), 
    add constraint FK_UniversalProgram_TresholdPointsRule_TresholdPointsRules 
    foreign key (UniversalProgramId) 
    references `LoyaltyProgram` (Id)
```

It saves bothe properties with correct discriminator, but during fetch AmountPointsRules get all records from BasePointsRule and proper bag for TresholdPoinstRules, but that it screams illegal access which seems to be correct, as AmountPoinstRules got all.

When I put abstract on BasePointsRule, there are two tables on database, foreigns keys properly referencing UniversalProgram and this works like a charm.

Question: is it possible to somehow override automappings to... i do not know ... set two constraints (for Amount and Treshold) or one for its base class?

Answer (score 2):

consider if you really need two strongly typed collections instead of using LINQ's `.OfType<>()`. If you do then add a filter condition

```
class BasePointsRuleMap : IAutoMappingOverride<UniversalProgram>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<UniversalProgram> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.AmountPointsRules).Where("basepointstype='AmountPointsRule'");
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.TresholdPointsRules).Where("basepointstype='TresholdPointsRule'");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with LINQ's `OfType<>()`, which would be good enough or even better, but I found problem with set, or I made some bad assumptions (or misunderstood concept) - as `BasePointsRule` can contains both types, `set` for `AmountPointsRule` and `TresholdPointsRule` should call add on `BasePointsRule` - after some fails I gave up and started with two strongly typed collections.

Comment: if you had problems with sets (ISet<>) maybe your equals and gethashcode implementation were wrong